# Reverse for 'LoginPage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I have created a project carpool.
The urls.py looks like :

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
                '',
                url(r'^$', include('register.urls', namespace = "register")),            
                       );
```

Created a app 'register' and urls.py looks like :

```
   urlpatterns = patterns(
                '',
   url('^$', Register.as_view(trigger = 0), name = 'LoginPage'),
   );
```

I have a login.html in register app and it extends base.html. Looks like this

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
```

I have base.html which looks like this :

```
***a href = "{%url 'LoginPage' %}"*** Register Login ...
```

The views in register is like this :

```
   class Register(View):
      # Object variables
      trigger = 0;
      logged_in = False;
      re_attempts = 0;

     def LoadLoginPage(self, request, message):
          return render(request, 
                       'login.html', 
                       {'title' : 'Login Page', 
                        'panel_message' : message});

     def get(self, request):
        if(self.trigger == 0):
            return self.LoadLoginPage(request, "Login here !");
```

When i load the initial page, i get the error :

> Reverse for 'LoginPage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

What could be the issue ?.

namespace is defined, name is defined (LoginPage), then what is the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The namespace *is* defined, but you never use it.

```
"{%url 'register:LoginPage' %}"
```

Answer (score 1):

When using namespaces, you have to also use them when resolving. Try something like:

```
{% url 'register:LoginPage' %}
```